# where clause in sql with multiple conditions based on priorities SQL BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, filter, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have two tables that I am merging together in BigQuery. I need to filter the data based on multiple conditions. I need to return all the fields where url = `https://www.mywebpage%`, duration = `15000` and the third condition should grab either action = `Midpoint` or action = `Complete`. Below is the code:

```
SELECT
    d.duration,
    c.action,
    c.url
FROM
    (
        `table_action_url` c
        INNER JOIN `table_duration` d ON (d.id = c.id)
    )
WHERE c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
AND d.duration = '15000' 
AND c.action like 'Midpoint' 
OR (c.action like 'Complete')
```

This returns different fields for duration and url, but right actions. I also tried the following:

```
SELECT
    d.duration,
    c.action,
    c.url
FROM
    (
        `table_action_url` c
        INNER JOIN `table_duration` d ON (d.id = c.id)
    )
WHERE (c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" AND d.duration = '15000' AND c.action like 'Midpoint')
OR (c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" AND d.duration = '15000' AND c.action like 'Complete')
```

This query returns the right url and duration but for action, the values are all Complete.
The desired output is:

```
duration      action      url 
15000        Midpoint     https://www.mywebpage
15000        Complete     https://www.mywebpage
15000        Midpoint     https://www.mywebpage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses.  Not in the `FROM` clause.  In the `WHERE` clause:

```
FROM `table_action_url` c JOIN
     `table_duration` d
      ON d.id = c.id
WHERE c.url LIKE 'https://www.mywebpage%' AND
      d.duration = '15000' AND
     (c.action LIKE 'Midpoint' OR c.action LIKE 'Complete')
```

In your particular case, you can replace the `LIKE` with `IN`:

```
WHERE c.url LIKE 'https://www.mywebpage%' AND
      d.duration = '15000' AND
      c.action IN ('Midpoint', 'Complete')
```

But if you want wildcard matching, use `regexp_contains()` instead:

```
WHERE c.url LIKE 'https://www.mywebpage%' AND
      d.duration = '15000' AND
      REGEXP_CONTAINS(c.action, '^(Midpoint|Complete)$'
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND` goes before `OR`...

You have:

```
WHERE (c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
       AND d.duration = '15000' 
       AND c.action like 'Midpoint')
OR (c.action like 'Complete')
```

But you want:

```
WHERE c.url LIKE "https://www.mywebpage%" 
AND d.duration = '15000' 
AND c.action in ('Midpoint', 'Complete')
```